# Waiting for the asynchronous result to come back, before executing rest of the code

Tags: angularjs, ajax, asynchronous, parse-server

I am writing this module in AngularJS, using ParseServer database to store and retrieve my objects.

When the module is initialised I want to query the database and display all sentences saved there as a list.

controller.js:

```
Parse.initialize("[APPID]", "[MASTERKEY]");
Parse.serverURL = 'http://localhost:1337/parse';
angular.module('CorrectionModule', ['ngMaterial', 'ngSanitize'])
.controller('SentenceCorrectionCtrl', ['$rootScope', '$mdDialog', '$scope',
    function($rootScope, $mdDialog, $scope) {
        $rootScope.sentences = [];

        var obj = Parse.Object.extend("Sentence");
        var queryObject = new Parse.Query(obj);

        queryObject.find({
            success: function(result) {
                for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                    $rootScope.sentences.push(result[i]);
                }
                console.log('Found ' + $rootScope.sentences.length + ' objects');
            },
            error: function(error) {
                console.log('Error ' + error.code + ': ' + error.message);
            }
        });

        $rootScope.currentUser = 'Student';
        $scope.switchUser = function() {
                if ($rootScope.currentUser == 'Teacher') {
                    $rootScope.currentUser = 'Student'
                } else if ($rootScope.currentUser == 'Student') {
                    $rootScope.currentUser = 'Teacher';
                }
            }

        $scope.addSentence = function() {
            var parentEl = angular.element(document.body);

            $mdDialog.show({
                parent: parentEl,
                templateUrl: "student-add-sentence.tmpl.html",
                controller: StudentAddController
            });

            function StudentAddController($scope, $mdDialog, $rootScope) {
                // $scope.user = $rootScope.currentUser;
                $scope.sentence = null;
                $scope.error = false;
                // SentenceObject = new Parse.Object('Sentence');

                $scope.saveSentence = function() {
                    if (!$scope.sentence){
                        $scope.error = 'Please add a sentence';
                    } else {
                        $scope.error = false;
                    }

                    if (!$scope.error){
                        // SentenceObject.set("sentence", $scope.sentence);
                        // SentenceObject.save(null, {
                        //     success: function(parseObject){
                        //         console.log('Saved[' + SentenceObject.id + ']: ' + $scope.sentence);
                        //         $rootScope.sentences.push($scope.sentence);
                        //         $scope.sentence = null;
                        //     },
                        //     error: function(parseObject, error) {
                        //         console.log('Error code: ' + error);
                        //     }
                        // });
                        $rootScope.sentences.push($scope.sentence);
                        $mdDialog.hide();
                    } 
                }

                $scope.cancel = function(){
                    $mdDialog.hide();
                }
            }
        }
    }
]);
```

index.html:

```
<html>
<title></title>

<head>
<!-- Angular Material CSS now available via Google CDN; version 1.0.7 used here -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/0.11.2/angular-material.min.css">
</head>

<body ng-app="CorrectionModule" ng-controller="SentenceCorrectionCtrl" layout="column">
<!-- Container #1 (see wireframe) -->
<md-toolbar layout="row">
    <h1>Correction</h1>
</md-toolbar>
<div>
    <md-button ng-click="addSentence()" ng-if="currentUser=='Student'">Add Sentence</md-button>
    <!-- <md-button ng-click="" ng-if="currentUser=='Teacher'"> -->
    <br/>
</div>
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="x in sentences">{{ x }}</li> 
</ul>
<md-button ng-click="switchUser()">Logged in as {{ currentUser }}</md-button>
<!-- Utilities script -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.parsecdn.com/js/parse-latest.js"></script>
<!-- Angular Material Dependencies -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
<!-- Angular Material Javascript now available via Google CDN; version 1.0.7 used here -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.7/angular-material.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
<!-- Custom controllers for different views -->
<script src="controller.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

The problem is that when I run the code it won't display anything, until I press the button that calls the dialog window.

The query runs asynchronously to the rest of the code, but I need it to run, and then the rest of the code can continue.

I have searched some other solutions involving making an explicit function that calls the result, but it has the same outcome.

Thank you in advance for help on this one.

Answer (score 2):

### To Wait for Asynchronous Results Use the [$q Service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)

**`$q`<sup>[1](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)</sup> -- A service that helps you run functions asynchronously, and use their return values (or exceptions) when they are done processing.**

To wait for asynchronous results to come back, before executing rest of the code, convert the `queryObject.find` call to a [`$q` service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) promise and then **chain** from that promise.

**Create Promise**

```
//Created Deferred Object
var findDeferred = $q.defer();

//Resolve Deferred Object;
queryObject.find({
    success: function(result) {
        findDeferred.resolve(result);
    },
    error: function(error) {
        findDeferred.reject(error);
    }
});

//Create promise from Deferred Object
var findPromise = findDeferred.promise;
```

**Chain From the Promise**

```
//Create derived promise
var derivedFindPromise = findPromise.then( function onSuccess(result) {
    var sentences = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        sentences.push(result[i]);
    }
    console.log('Found ' + sentences.length + ' objects');
    //return to chain data
    return sentences;
}).catch( function onReject(error) {
    console.log('Error ' + error.code + ': ' + error.message);
    //throw to chain error
    throw error;
});

//Use derived promise
derivedFindPromise.then(function onSuccess2(sentences) {
    $scope.sentences = sentences;
    //Call subsequent functions here
});
```

> Because calling the `.then` method of a promise returns a new derived promise, it is easily possible to create a chain of promises.
>
> It is possible to create chains of any length and since a promise can be resolved with another promise (which will defer its resolution further), it is possible to pause/defer resolution of the promises at any point in the chain. This makes it possible to implement powerful APIs.

-- [AngularJS $q Service API Reference -- Chaining promises](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#chaining-promises)

Comment: Thank you this helped, it synchronises everything together

Answer (score -1):

If you wrap the rest of the code in a single function, you can just call that function from the inside of the success. Is there a reason why this wouldn't work?

Alternatively, you could use a boolean variable to mark whether or not the rest of the code should run. Then use $interval to test the variable until it is ready. Here's a small example of that.

```
var isReady = false;

...
queryObject.find({
    success: function() {
        isReady = true;
    },
    error: function() {
        ...
    });
...

var interval = $interval(function() {
    if (isReady) {
     // call the code you want to execute 
     // after the async operation is finished
    }
}, 500); // how often you want to check if the operation is finished
```